# ¿Como convertir NSData a NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Tengo una variable `nsdata` que es un arreglo de bytes, y lo quiero como cadena en string, pero no quiero decodificarlo, solo quiero tener la misma trama pero en string.

```
nsdata = <024101e6 90eaf082 01e0df42 020002df 3d106967 e83efea5 c7bfe062 dca4737b 101bdf16 088c9877>
```

y quiero tenerlo exactamente igual pero como string:

```
nsstring = "<024101e6 90eaf082 01e0df42 020002df 3d106967 e83efea5 c7bfe062 dca4737b 101bdf16 088c9877>";
```

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suponiendo que `nsdata` es de tipo `NSData *`, puedes usar:

```
NSString *str = [nsdata description];
```

Comment: Excelente esto era la soluciòn, las que usan encoding siempre lo tratan de pasar a otro formato y salen simbolos,  ya que no son palabras lo que yo estoy transformando.

Answer (score 0):

Esta sería la forma, definiendo un encoding mediante [NSString](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring) :

```
NSString *miString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
```

Comment: Gracias, lo probe pero marcaba algunos errores de que no podia usar autorelease, pero  NSString *str = [nsdata description]; es la solucion que me funciono, gracias por responder.